# Handling text containing both quote types

Tags: bash

I want to append the following text to a file in Linux:

```
echo He said "I can't append this" >> file.txt
cat file.txt
He said I can't append this
```

The [closest solution I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20904183/1156245) doesn't work.  How do I include both sets of quotes in the appended string?

Comment: `echo "He said \"I can't append this\""  =>
He said "I can't append this"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better to use [here-doc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to avoid crazy escaping:

```
cat<<'EOF' > file.txt
He said "I can't append this"
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate strings as in:

```
echo He said '"'"I can't append this"'"'
```

or:

```
echo 'He said "I can'"'"'t append this"'
```

but probably the best option is use the `\` escape character:

```
echo 'He said "I can\'t append this"' # note: this is wrong - see comment
```

**EDIT:** As noted in @gniourf_gniourf's comment the previous solution with the escape character is wrong. The correct version is

```
echo "He said \"I can't append this\""
```

Comment: Your last solution (presented as the best option) doesn't work: as the string is within single quotes, the backslash doesn't behave as an escape character, and the following single quote closes the first one.

Comment: Also, you can't escape a single quote inside single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the use of `cat`, you can use `printf`:

```
printf 'He said "%s"\n' "I can't append this" >> file.txt
```